# How to include cursor with page screenshot captured via Electron's capturePage API?

Tags: electron

I’m attempting to capture a screenshot of a `webview` via calling its `webContents`’ `capturePage` method. I had assumed that a cursor would be included with the screenshot, but it’s not.

Any ideas on how best to achieve including a cursor with the screenshot taken via a capturePage call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `webContents.capturePage ()` won't include the cursor because the screenshot is not made on an OS-level.

Electron takes the screenshot directly after Chromium has rendered it, which is also why the `rect` property to the function cannot be bigger than the window's inner width and height, i.e. the window decoration, such as titlebars, etc., cannot be included in the screenshot.

What Electron does is to take the binary image data which is output to the graphics processor of your computer (and thus to your monitor), and writes it to a PNG or JPEG file.

Including OS-specific elements such as cursors or window decorations would involve a platform-specific approach (as there is no unified API to take screenshots throughout Linux, Windows and Mac OS), which creates (possibly) more dependencies and more noise. The rendering done by the Chromium engine is platform-agnostic and thus the way easier approach.

Comment: Maybe you could mention/include an approach to add a cursor icon into the captured image. Getting the cursor location relative to the `webContents` should be doable.

Comment: @snwflk I think that is better suited in an answer to a separate question, as it requires image manipulation, etc.

Comment: I've learnt to attempt to answer the exact question, so I'd argue that would include image manipulation. Of course, I see your point of separate concerns.